# Having issue with Main.storyboard in Xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I made a Flutter application on my personal computer ( Windows OS). I sent it to my MacBook and I am trying to run and build my app in Xcode.

When I first set up my application I was getting a build input error so I made a path for these files under output files. Now I can finally successfully build my app but I get this error in the log box and the app won't open.

```
Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path '/Users/tannerresearch1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-csfusvksoxtqdffsramggvnsopwf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app'- using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices.
objc[4504]: Class AKAlertImageURLProvider is implemented in both /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21C62/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.2.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AuthKitUI.framework/AuthKitUI (0x148ff6628) and /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21C62/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.2.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AuthKit.framework/AuthKit (0x1269ee9a0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle </Users/tannerresearch1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/47B480FA-C394-495C-A385-66B47603C4E1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9FCBA5CB-CE15-410B-946C-8DCE98575B6D/Runner.app> (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110a9b761 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110124904 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKitCore                           0x0000000140864f87 -[UIStoryboard name] + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00000001406627d1 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 75
    4   UIKitCore                           0x0000000140662d51 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 276
    5   UIKitCore                           0x0000000140661802 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 990
    6   UIKitCore                           0x000000013f994fc1 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 122
    7   UIKitCore                           0x000000014007bf44 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 87
    8   UIKitCore                           0x000000013f995b1f __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 198
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000013f995580 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 249
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000013f995968 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 813
    11  UIKitCore                           0x000000013f995194 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 341
    12  UIKitCore                           0x000000013f9a26fb __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_blo  13  UIKitCore                           0x000000013ff2bb08 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:] + 865
    14  UIKitCore                           0x000000014009a563 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion + 261
    15  UIKitCore                           0x000000013f9a238a -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 347
    16  UIKitCore                           0x000000013f774caa __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.610 + 877
    17  UIKitCore                           0x000000013f77365f -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 245
    18  UIKitCore                           0x000000013f774812 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 252
    19  UIKitCore                           0x000000014066014f -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 672
    20  UIKitCore                           0x000000013ff60d31 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 353
    21  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000124f6c63f -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 406
    22  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000124f9f056 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.254 + 279
    23  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000124f7c353 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 213
    24  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000124f9ed50 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 328
    25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001102809f7 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110284389 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 507
    27  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000124fca9a7 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    28  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000124fca881 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 188
    29  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000124fca9cf -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 19
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109f8283 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109f81c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 157
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109f79c2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 215
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109f20f7 __CFRunLoopRun + 919
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109f197d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
    35  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001240cb08f GSEventRunModal + 137
    36  UIKitCore                           0x000000014065e53d -[UIApplication _run] + 972
    37  UIKitCore                           0x0000000140662fab UIApplicationMain + 123
    38  Runner                              0x000000010276347f main + 63
    39  dyld                                0x000000010c5023e0 start_sim + 10
    40  ???                                 0x0000000203c50386 0x0 + 8653177734
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6
```

I tried moving my LaunchScreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard back to CopyBundleResources under Build Phases but then I just get the build input error again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.